# onclick event is not working when adding dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a function through `onclick` attribute but I m getting the function undefined error. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/2/)

```
(function() {
  function getInfo(x) {
    console.log(x)
  }

  function a() {
    var x = [{
      "name": "main",
      "data": ['1', '2', '3']
    }, {
      "name": "sub",
      "data": ['4', '5', '6']
    }, {
      "name": "lower",
      "data": ['7', '8', '9']
    }]
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      var data = "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>main </span>";
      data += "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>sub </span>"
      data += "<span onclick='getInfo(" + x[i].data + ")'>lower</span><br>"
      $('#data').prepend(data);
    }


  }
  a()
})()
```

Comment: You've hidden the `getInfo()` function inside the IIFE function. Move it outside to be global so that the handlers can find it.

Comment: You are silently casting x[i].data which is an array into a string, this will most likely give unexpected results

Comment: @WalleCyril: you are right. Can you please tell me how to fix this problem.

Comment: JSON.stringify could do the trick: `"<span onclick='getInfo("+JSON.stringify(x[i].data)+")'>main </span>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason you get `undefined` is because the `onclick` will try to find the function in the global scope, while your `getInfo` function is defined within a function scope.

Then you should make `getInfo` a property of the global scope (`window`) to fix the issue. For example:

```
window.getInfo = function(x) {
    console.log(x)
}
```

See the updated fiddle.js here: https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/6/

Comment: Can you explain why a normal function won't work here? I mean, why `window.getInfo = function(x)` works and `function getInfo(x)` doesn't?

Comment: I think I kind of explained in my answer. The way I think of it is that the inline event handlers can only find a function in the global scope. (this may be a limitation in browsers?)  - There are better ways to attach an onclick event to an element, for example using `addEventlistener` more is explained here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: @Filype: Why window.getInfo work when function getInfo did not even if we put the function getInfo on global scope

Comment: @Carlos, I am pretty sure it would work if the function is placed in the global scope with the same name.  To try this I would suggest a `script` tag inside your HTML with only the function.  I am pretty sure this will have the same effect.

Comment: @Carlos I have updated the fiddler with the function in the global scope: https://jsfiddle.net/fddr0bnv/7/